# Did Walt Disney accidentally kill someone during a game of polo?

Tags: history

In [a recent episode](https://youtu.be/xfCuDG15M1U?t=521) of the somewhat popular series "James & Mike Mondays", Mike Matei makes the claim that he once read on a card of the game *Trivial Pursuit* that Walt Disney once kill somebody by accident during a game of polo.

He further claimed that information on the incident is hard to find and implied that the Disney Corporation may have attempted to keep this information hidden.

Here is a transcript of the episode *(Emphasis mine)*:

> *Mike:* I was playing Trivial Pursuit one time and I'm playing Trivial Pursuit and I pull up a card and there is a question in it and I read it and it says: "**How many people did Walt Disney kill?**" And you flip it over and the choices were 0, 1, 2 or 3.
>
> *James:* Is this a joke question or...?
>
> *Mike:* It's not a joke question.
>
> *James:* Okay.
>
> *Mike:* And I'm like "Well, zero! He didn't kill- It's Walt Disney! He didn't kill anybody." **And the answer was I think one.** So, there was a game of polo and it was a polo accident--
>
> *James (at the same time):* Okay...
>
> *Mike:* --that happened and **apparently he killed somebody during a game of polo, by accident!**

Are there any reliable sources that confirm that this happened? Or is this an urban myth?

Comment: According to a [biography of Will Rogers](https://books.google.com/books?id=JEzy-vUA6_sC&lpg=PA268&ots=2_tf-OBa8N&dq=walt%20disney%20%22polo%20accident%22&pg=PA268#v=onepage&q=walt%20disney%20%22polo%20accident%22&f=false), he did.  See also "Walt Disney: The Triumph of the American Imagination" p281, which states that his horse fell on Gordon Wescott, who died 3 days later.

Comment: @Ashelly: Please post that as an answer, so it can be voted upon, etc.

Comment: Do we [count his mother](https://www.express.co.uk/life-style/life/521551/Walt-Disney-mum-death-film-characters-motherless), that he blamed himself for? Even though it wasn't in a game of polo.

Comment: @Fizz Unless he was directly the cause or at least involved in her death, I would not say so

Comment: Walt Disney did not directly kill the men, but my great grandmother's cousin, Gordon Westcott died from injuries at a polo match with Disney.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Actually, this is incorrect.

Evidently, the answer is **2** to the Trivial Pursuit question.

As to whether Walt Disney **killed** someone, I would say the answer is **No**. Two men did die while playing polo in games with Disney but neither man's death was attributed to him.

According to Michael Barrier, an animation historian, the **Trivial Pursuit** question was actually:

> How many people died from injuries incurred playing polo with Walt
>   Disney?

From his blog:

> A few days ago, Thad Komorowski posted on his blog a card from the
>   1985 Disney edition of Trivial Pursuit, which included this unusual
>   question: "How many people died from injuries incurred playing polo
>   with Walt Disney?" Trivial Pursuit's answer: **two**. Thad asked me to
>   provide some more details, and I did, *at this link*. The two deaths
>   were those of **Gordon Westcott**, an actor, in October 1935, and **Winslow
>   Felix**, an auto dealer, in May 1936. Both men were fatally injured
>   during matches at the Riviera Country Club.

Unfortunately, the link is broken and I couldn't find a copy on the Wayback Machine.

[Here](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/30981998/) is a scan of page 218 of The Ogden Standard-Examiner from 31 oct 1935, referring to the *basal skull injury suffered in a polo game*:

> THURSDAY EVENING, OCTOBER 31, 1935. RELATIVES OF DEAD ACTOR TO ATTEND RITE: Ogden People Prepare To Leave For West Coast Services Ogden relatives of Gordon Westcott handsome character actor of the films, who died Thursday in Hollywood from a basal skull injury suffered in a polo game, were preparing today to attend his funeral which will probably be held , in the Warner Brothers studios.

The men's deaths seem to be from being crushed or thrown by a horse so I don't know if saying **Walt Disney kill** is accurate.

> both newspapers said that Westcott was crushed under his own horse.

Winslow Felix was [apparently injured](http://articles.latimes.com/2005/apr/03/local/me-then3/2) and died in a collision with another rider.

> On May 31, 1936, Felix was playing in a polo match on the Freebooters
>   team against the Riviera Blues at the Riviera Country Club. Minutes
>   into the hotly contested match, Felix's horse collided with Reginald
>   "Snowy" Baker's mount, throwing both riders to the ground.
>
> Baker ignored injuries to his head and shoulder to get himself and
>   Felix off the field before they were trampled. Baker went back to the
>   game while Felix was rushed to the hospital, where he died the next
>   day of a head injury. He was 42.

On an unrelated note, Felix Winslow's auto dealership still uses Felix the Cat in its sign. He once gave a car to Felix cartoon producer, Pat Sullivan, who let him use the cat.
[image: Photo of sign]

[Source: michaelbarrier.com](http://www.michaelbarrier.com/Home%20Page/WhatsNewArchivesMayJune2008.html)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to upvote this if we could get the obituaries or something other than just a blog.

Comment: https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/18678 and http://articles.latimes.com/2005/apr/03/local/me-then3/2 might serve as the start of such an evidence trail.

Comment: Found (and added) obituary for Westcott. Felix is harder. https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/61101864/winslow-b.-felix

Comment: I would explicitly state that the collision that lead to Winslow's death did not involve Disney, "Felix was engaged in a ride-off with Snowy Baker, veteran polo player, when his horse stumbled and collided with Baker's mount. Both Felix and Baker were unseated." (from @JanDoggen 's link) clearly disproving "Disney kill" for one, but that leaves the original claim of one accidental killing still possible.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - I did manage to find a recent (2005) LA Times article that mentions his death. I am **ass**u**me**ing that is relatively accurate in the details of his demise.

Comment: Do we have any verification that those games included Walt Disney as a player?